# subscription in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I want to subscribe report on specific schedule in reporting services 2008. i.e report will dilever to user automatically on schedule. I am using visual studio 2008. I have done the configuration setting (rsreportserver.config, app.config after adding refrences of asmx files) by refrence msdn. The code is running fine (no exception occur) and I also get subscription id through calling create subscription indicate all going fine. But after running the code no entry made in Subscription table of ReportServer database. And also not get any mail. While through report server web tool, I can get email and also entery made in database but not from coe. Please someone help me. What I am missing. Plz help

Code is given follow: (Keep in mind, I am using VS2008)

```
void SendReportEmail()
{
RSServiceReference.ReportingService2005SoapClient rs=new RSServiceReference.ReportingService2005SoapClient();

rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = new System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel(); 

string batchID = string.Empty;
RSServiceReference.ServerInfoHeader infoHeader = rs.CreateBatch(out batchID);
BatchHeader bh = new BatchHeader()
{
    BatchID = batchID,
    AnyAttr = infoHeader.AnyAttr
};

string report = "/PCMSR6Reports/PaymentRequestStatusMIS";
string desc = "Send email from code to Hisham@comsoft.com";
string eventType = "TimedSubscription";

string scheduleXml="<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><StartDateTime xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices\">2010-03-06T15:15:00.000+05:00</StartDateTime></ScheduleDefinition>";

RSServiceReference.ParameterValue[] extensionParams = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue[7];     

extensionParams[0] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[0].Name = "TO";
extensionParams[0].Value = "Hisham@comsoft.com";

extensionParams[1] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[1].Name = "IncludeReport";
extensionParams[1].Value = "True";

extensionParams[2] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[2].Name = "RenderFormat";
extensionParams[2].Value = "MHTML";

extensionParams[3] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[3].Name = "Subject";
extensionParams[3].Value = "@ReportName was executed at @ExecutionTime";

extensionParams[4] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[4].Name = "Comment";
extensionParams[4].Value = "Here is your test report for testing purpose";

extensionParams[5] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[5].Name = "IncludeLink";
extensionParams[5].Value = "True";

extensionParams[6] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
extensionParams[6].Name = "Priority";
extensionParams[6].Value = "NORMAL";

RSServiceReference.ParameterValue[] parameters = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue[10];

parameters[0] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
parameters[0].Name = "BranchId";
parameters[0].Value = "1";

parameters[1] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
parameters[1].Name = "UserName";
parameters[1].Value = "admin";

parameters[2] = new RSServiceReference.ParameterValue();
parameters[2].Name = "SupplierId";
parameters[2].Value = "0";

string matchData = scheduleXml;
RSServiceReference.ExtensionSettings extSettings = new RSServiceReference.ExtensionSettings();
extSettings.ParameterValues = extensionParams;
extSettings.Extension = "Report Server Email";
try
{
   string sub="";
   RSServiceReference.ServerInfoHeader SubID = rs.CreateSubscription(bh, report, extSettings, desc, eventType, matchData, parameters, out sub);

   rs.FireEvent(bh, "TimedSubscription", sub); 

}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}
}
```

Detail response will be highly appricated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @ at the beginning of your xml string @"